# Quick SQL question: Correct syntax for creating a table with a primary key in H2?

Tags: sql, database, h2, create-table

I'm currently starting a new Java application using the [H2 database](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html), but I have some confusion about basic SQL use for creating tables.  How do I make a table of entries (strings) each with unique, auto-incrementing, non-null, integer primary keys?  One of the most basic things to do, but I'm not sure offhand what the correct way to do it with H2 is.

I blame these for my confusion (specifies more than one way of doing the same thing between different databases; can't figure the right way for H2, though):
http://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_primarykey.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_autoincrement.asp

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If I'm reading the H2 documentation correctly, this should work:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTableName(PKFieldName IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, StringFieldName VARCHAR(255))
```

Basically, you just want to declare your key column to be of type `IDENTITY`.

For `IDENTITY` type see: http://www.h2database.com/html/datatypes.html#identity_type
For `CREATE TABLE` syntax see: http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#create_table

Comment: Identity does all of that?  Ok I'll give it a shot.  Thanks.